# Getting an argument in a specific position for further piped processing

Tags: linux, pipe

Sometimes I need to kill a specific process which is listening on a known port in order to free that port up.

When I execute `sudo lsof -n -i :1084`, in order to get the PID of the process listening on port `1084`, I get the following result

```
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    1603   pi   11u  IPv4  26101      0t0  TCP *:1084 (LISTEN)
sshd    1603   pi   12u  IPv6  26102      0t0  TCP *:1084 (LISTEN)
```

With `grep -P 'IPv4.+LISTEN'` I can obtain the line where a process is listening on that port, using IPv4

Executing

```
sudo lsof -n -i :1084 | grep -P 'IPv4.+LISTEN'
```

returns

```
sshd    1603   pi   11u  IPv4  26101      0t0  TCP *:1084 (LISTEN)
```

How can I now get `1603` so I can pass that one to `kill`?

I tried with grep, sed (`sudo lsof -n -i :1084 | grep -P 'IPv4.+LISTEN' | sed -E 's/sshd\ +(\d+)\ /\1/g'`) but I just don't know how.

There must be a command like `sudo lsof -n -i :1084 | grep -P 'IPv4.+LISTEN' | xargs --no-run-if-empty kill {$second_argument}'` which would allow me to archive that goal, any ideas?

Also, if it's not a solution with `sed`, what would a solution using `sed` look like (I could use that in other cases)?

Comment: How to give arguments to kill via pipe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653921/how-to-give-arguments-to-kill-via-pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I now get 1603 so I can pass that one to kill?

That is a job for `awk`:

```
sudo lsof -n -i :1084 | grep -P 'IPv4.+LISTEN' | awk '{print $2}'
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Linux command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/)
- [awk gawk Man Page - Linux - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/awk.html)